# How could I find the indexes of data in each cluster after applying the PCA and a clustering method?

Tags: python, data-science, cluster-analysis, k-means, pca

I would like to order each point of the plot to its corresponding index in the table. 
Here are the first three lines of data I'm working with. 
[image: data to analyse] 
After applying the PCA (2D) to my data, I get a plot similar to this, and then I use the kmeans algorithm for clustering.  
[image: (possible)clustering using kmeans].
Suppose I take all data in the red cluster. How could I find the indexes of those data set in the table ?
Or how could I find the indexes of each point in the table ?
The goal is to be able to order each point in the plot to its corresponding line in the table.  I use Python. 
Articles or documents that explain it will also be welcome. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the indexes of points in each cluster as below.

Suppose **data** with **12 samples** each with **three features**. PCA is used to decrease the number of features. Then, k-means is used to cluster the data.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import decomposition

data=np.array([[5,4.5,6],[1,1,2],[1,2,1.5],[8,8.5,8],[2,2.5,1.5],[4,4.5,5],[8.5,8,9],[4,6,5.5],[5,6,5],[8,9,8.5],[9,9,8],[9,8,9]])

pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=2) # apply pca
pca.fit(data)
data2 = pca.transform(data) # new data saved in data2
print("data with two features:\n", data2)
plt.plot(data2[:,0],data2[:,1],'ro')
for i in range(data2.shape[0]):        
        plt.text(data2[i,0],data2[i,1], str(i), fontsize=12)
plt.show()

#run Kmeans on data2 with 3 clusters
km=KMeans(n_clusters=3) # number of clusters =3 
km=km.fit(data2)
cluster_labels=km.labels_ # get cluster label of all data
print("cluster labels of points:", cluster_labels)

# get indexes of points in each cluster 
#Note: you can use these indexes in both data and data2
index_cluster_0=np.where(cluster_labels==0)[0] # get indexes of points in cluster 0 
print("indexes of points in cluster 0:", index_cluster_0)
index_cluster_1=np.where(cluster_labels==1)[0] # get indexes of points in cluster 1
print("indexes of points in cluster 1:", index_cluster_1)
index_cluster_2=np.where(cluster_labels==2)[0] # get indexes of points in cluster 2
print("indexes of points in cluster 2:", index_cluster_2)

#plot the results
plt.plot(data2[index_cluster_0,0],data2[index_cluster_0,1],'ro') #samples in cluster 0 are red
plt.plot(data2[index_cluster_1,0],data2[index_cluster_1,1],'bo') #samples in cluster 1 are blue
plt.plot(data2[index_cluster_2,0],data2[index_cluster_2,1],'go') #samples in cluster 2 are green
plt.title('Cluster 0: red, Cluster 1: blue, Cluster 2: green')
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
 data with two features:
 [[ 0.78528736  1.06750913]
 [ 7.42907267  0.7576433 ]
 [ 7.15249919 -0.32552917]
 [-4.40158551 -0.37613828]
 [ 6.26503561 -0.55127462]
 [ 1.95747537  0.30362524]
 [-4.9903965   0.69673761]
 [ 0.83759652 -0.57439496]
 [ 0.51143086 -0.70659728]
 [-4.96288343 -0.46968141]
 [-5.28904909 -0.60188372]
 [-5.29448305  0.77998415]]
```

[image]

```
cluster labels of points: [2 1 1 0 1 2 0 2 2 0 0 0]
indexes of points in cluster 0: [ 3  6  9 10 11]
indexes of points in cluster 1: [1 2 4]
indexes of points in cluster 2: [0 5 7 8]
```

[image]

Note that you can use the obtained indexes in both original data and the data achieved by PCA.

Comment: Thank you @Roy for this suggestion. I will look at it.